# Finding the Smallest Number with p^n Divisors (p is Prime)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am attempting to find the smallest number with $2^{500500}$ divisors. I stumbled across an [old paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315183?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) which appears to detail a method for doing just this; however I don't understand it well enough to make use of it.[image: Excerpt from paper]

Above is an excerpt from the paper. $A(h)$ is a function that outputs the smallest number with $h$ divisors. What confuses me most is his description of the $G(i, l)$ function. I understand that $i$ is used as an index to $p$, but I don't know how I would go about finding $l$, which is used to determine the exponent for any given $p$.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D2JM2oImb9Qg&ved=2ahUKEwjwqrut6JnjAhUIc98KHS_SBTsQwqsBMAB6BAgFEAU&usg=AOvVaw0KGXuSRjBIP8hn7q1COu3p

Comment: note that they seem to be looking for exactly $p^n$ divisors, which is very restrictive. Suggest you find the smallest numbers with exactly 2, 4, 8 divisors. Compare with  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number  Evidently exactly 8 divisors and exactly 32 divisors are not SHC numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I was originally confused about the function $G(i, l) = p_i^{(q-1)q^{(l-1)}}$. I now believe I understand the equation and how to use it. $p_i$ is merely referencing the "ith" prime number. $q$ is some fixed prime value (in my case it would be 2). $l$ can range from 1 to $\infty$. The numbers generated by $G(i, l)$ can then be used to find the smallest number with $q^n$ divisors. This is done by sorting the results of $G(i, l)$ for incrementally increasing values of $i$ and $l$ and then multiplying the first $n$ sorted values.